# how to bulid a json object in server client with C#

Tags: c#, json

I provide data in server ,and want to send it to client,I use ashx with method ProcessRequest.

```
    public override void ProcessRequest ( HttpContext context )
    {
       string html="";
       //do sth for get html
         context.Response.Write ( html.ToString() );
    }
```

in client ,I render page with ajax.
so, I want get a json object in client, how to do it? how to bulid a json in sever side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [JSON serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx) in .net version >= 3.5.
A little example:

```
[DataContract]
class Student
{
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int Age { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof (Student));
  var student = new Student {Name = "Jonh", Age = 18};
  var stream = new MemoryStream();
  serializer.WriteObject(stream, student);
  var jsonString = Encoding.Default.GetString(stream.ToArray());

}
```

You can find `DataContractJsonSerializer` in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Comment: if i has 2 line ,eg: new Student {Name = "Jonh", Age = 18}; new Student {Name = "felix", Age = 22}; how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean serialize collection of objects?

Comment: It,s more difficult to do that by standart serializer... But you can implement serialization of list<keyValuePair>

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataContractJsonSerializer to achieve this.
Define your response

```
[DataContract]
class Response
{
    [DataMember]
    private string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then serialize your html-response into output stream:

```
Response response = new Response();
response.Content = html.ToString();
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
serializer.WriteObject(context.Response.Stream,response);
```

Answer (score 1):

If .net 2.0, you can try [litjson](http://litjson.sourceforge.net/)